# Transaction scope with Entity Framework parallel contexts

Tags: c#, entity-framework, parallel-processing, transactionscope

```
        using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = System.Transactions.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
        {
            var id = ((Func<int>)delegate ()
            {
                using (var context = new MyContext())
                {
                    var order = new Order { Name = "Test", Flags = 1 };
                    context.Orders.Add(order);
                    context.SaveChanges();
                    return order.ID;
                }
            }).Invoke();

            Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
            {
                using (var context = new MyContext())
                {
                    var order = context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(order => order.ID == id);

                    if (order == null)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {x} could not find order.");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {x} found order.");
                        //TODO: further processing.
                    }
                }
            });

            scope.Complete();
        }
```

I am trying to create, update and get entities from the context in a parallel environment. As you can see the code above, Once I create an Order using a context outside the parallel loop and then inside the parallel loop I try to retrieve the newly created Order but **only one or two threads** are able to find it .

I tried using different levels of **IsolationLevel** but the outcome is still the same.

Is there something wrong with this implementation ?

Answer (score 1):

As stated on the [`TransactionScope` documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx) you should also use [`DependentTransaction`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.dependenttransaction.aspx) when dealing with multi-threading scenarios.

From the `TransactionScope` MSDN [page](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx#Anchor_4):

> You should also use the TransactionScope and DependentTransaction
>   class for applications that require the use of the same transaction
>   across multiple function calls or multiple thread calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you implement what @polkduran suggested on MSDN you will start getting System.Data.Entity.Core.EntityExceptions that relate to the database connection. So when I add a lock to the bit of code that creates the reading DbContext the exceptions stop occurring:

```
    object locker = new object();

    using (var scope = new TransactionScope(TransactionScopeOption.Required, new TransactionOptions { IsolationLevel = IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted }))
    {
        int id;
        using (var context = new MyContext())
        {
            var order = new Order { Name = "Test", Flags = 1 };
            context.Orders.Add(order);
            context.SaveChanges();
            id = order.Id;
        }

        var transactionToUse = Transaction.Current.DependentClone(DependentCloneOption.BlockCommitUntilComplete);

        Enumerable.Range(1, 10).AsParallel().ForAll(x =>
        {
            lock (locker)
            {
                using (var ts = new TransactionScope(transactionToUse))
                {
                    using (var context = new MyContext())
                    {
                        var orderItem = context.Orders.FirstOrDefault(order => order.Id == id);

                        if (orderItem == null)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {x} could not find order.");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {x} found order.");
                            //TODO: further processing.
                        }
                    }
                    ts.Complete();
                }
            }    
        });

        scope.Complete();
    }
```

I guess the shared connection across multiple threads with different connection states creates race conditions for each instance of DbContext that is created.